React native stripe charge the customer for payment after complete the trip
I’m developing a react native, firebase, and stripe taxi app, where there are 2 apps (user and driver).
At user app, I would like to make user add card with 3D secure authentication and authenticate once.
At driver app, driver mark complete and then only charge user’s card for payment.
At user app, user do not need to authenticate for the following trips.
May I know is the flow correct or which flow/process should I use?
which stripe API should I use?

You want the SetupIntent flow in ReactNative, covered in https://docs.stripe.com/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=react-native&mobile-ui=payment-element. The Doc has step-by-step guide to implement it.
